# My values keep adding up, instead of resetting in my loop statement

Tags: c++

I'm not sure whether one of my formulas are wrong, I placed something in the wrong area, or I'm missing something completely. But when I run the prog. It would add up the prices of meals from a previous table of customers, instead of resetting for each new table. Any help?

```
int main ()
{    
  //These are the variables used for the formulas and inputs.
  int people, counter;
  float price, subtotal, tip, tax, total;
  cout<<"How many people are at the table?" <<endl;
  cin>>people;
  //Use a while statement to start a loop
  while (people!=0)
   {
  //Use a for statement inside the while to make a nested loop. It will ask the price of each meal.
  for(counter=1; counter<=people; counter++)
    {
      cout<<"How much is the meal?: " <<endl;
      cin>>price;
        subtotal+=price;
        tax=subtotal*.06;
      if (people<5)
        {
          tip=subtotal*.18;
        }
      else
      tip=subtotal*.20;
      total=tax+subtotal+tip;

    }
  //This is the final output for the program. Which will be the bill.
  cout<<setprecision(2) <<fixed;
  cout<<left;
  cout<<setw(20)<<"Subtotal: " <<"$" <<subtotal <<endl;
  cout<<setw(20)<<"Sales Tax: " <<"$" <<tax <<endl;
  cout<<setw(20)<<"Tip: " <<"$" <<tip <<endl;
  cout<<setw(20)<<"Total: " <<"$" <<total <<endl;
  cout<<" " <<endl;
  cout<<setw(20)<<"How many people are at the table?" <<endl;
  cin>>people;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to reset all your variables to 0 inside the `while` loop and just before the `for`, especially `subtotal`

Comment: Just curious, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You could also define your variables only within the while loop. Make sure you use default values to initialize

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a beginner's code (-:

Not initializing your variables is very bad programming, especially in C++.
You MUST do that (on variables creation)!!
FYI: Not initialized = contains garbage (undefined value).

You should change `subtotal+=price;` to `subtotal=price;`

and `total=tax+subtotal+tip;` to `total+=tax+subtotal+tip;`

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead of for loops

int counter = 1;  // Don't forget to declare variables

while ( counter <= people ) {

// use your price formulas here

```
cout<< your desired outputs <<endl;
counter++;             // Update counter so the condition can be met eventually
```

}